# When Creating a CSS Snippet to modify ObsidianMD's bullet list's bullets, why does the class '.cm-list-4' work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, obsidian

Can someone explain to me why when modifying the style of bullet lists, you can only go three levels deep using `.cm-list-n` where `n` is level?

The following doesn't work:

```
.cm-list-4 .list-bullet:before {
    content: '\25AA';
}
```

This, however does:

```
.HyperMD-list-line-4 .list-bullet:before {
    content: '\2024';
}
```

I'm still relatively novice in CSS styling. Using the Developer tools, I see that at the fourth level it cycles back to using '.cm-list-1' -- is this an inherent mechanic of how Obsidian creates the lists?

[CSS Inspection View of Fourth Level Bullet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8M03.png)

Is `.HyperMD-list-line` a parent of `.cm-list-n` and has precedence such that `.HyperMD-list-line-4` overrides `.cm-list-1` at the fourth level or something along those lines?

I attempted to dissect the source CSS and app.css to understand better how ObsidianMD applies styling but I'm still novice at CSS so my understanding is a bit shaky.